# There was an issue while playing(Playback ID :i_1zhUdtNxOiyfBO) Tap to retry

Tags: android, youtube-api

Error occurs while i m trying to play youtube video url in my android application using youtubeplayer.jar library only on android version 7.0 nougat[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M75H1.jpg)

Comment: Check this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/77wPU2gtt24), you may be encountering this due to network related issue. You can also see the [support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4517880?vid=0-980019758934-1501429195022) on how to troubleshoot Android app issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hello had this issues before an hour
Try following solutions.

1-Retstart phone.

OR

2-You could try to clear the data of the YouTube application:
Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Youtube -> Force Stop -> Clear Data

May be it will work with you also